# Merge multiple query results into one using case

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, left-join

I have a user-table which contains users information with the fields `user_id, fullname, age, username, password` and other is `tests-table` with the fields `id, user_id, test_type`

When I write the below query

```
select users.user_id, fullname,
(CASE WHEN test_table.user_id=users.id and test_table.type = 'objectives'   THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS written_objectives, 
(CASE WHEN test_table.user_id=users.id and test_table.type = 'theory'   THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS written_theory, 

from users

LEFT JOIN test_table ON users.id = test_table.user_id
WHERE users.user_id = 1
```

I get the results like this

```
user_id|fullname| test_type | written_objectives| written_theory
1      | Ben.   | objectivs |       yes         | no
1      | Ben.   | theory    |       no          | yes
```

But I want the results like this

```
user_id|fullname| test_type | written_objectives| written_theory
1      | Ben.   | objectivs |       yes         | yes
```

From the above scenario, the user with `id` of `1` has submitted both objectives and theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select u.user_id, u.fullname,
    max(tt.type = 'objectives') written_objectives, 
    max(tt.type = 'theory'    ) written_theory
from users u
left join test_table tt on u.id = tt.user_id
where u.user_id = 1 
group by u.user_id
```

This generates `0`/`1` values rather than `'yes'`/`'no'` - which I find more expressive. But if you really want thoses strings, then:

```
select u.user_id, u.fullname,
    case when max(tt.type = 'objectives') then 'yes' else 'no' end written_objectives, 
    case when max(tt.type = 'theory'    ) then 'yes' else 'no' end written_theory
from users u
left join test_table tt on u.id = tt.user_id
where u.user_id = 1 
group by u.user_id
```

Notes:

- there is no need to repeat the join condition in the conditional expression - the `left join` handles that already
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read